# How does handling an interrupt affects a multi-threaded user space process?

Tags: scheduling, interrupt

Say, I put a breakpoint (`int 3` from now on) somewhere in a user space process code. One of the threads hits the breakpoint... And what happens next? My judgement is: this is an interrupt, so it is handled in the kernel. I don't really care about the signals and interrupt handlers and stuff, I just want to know what happens to the other threads of the user space process. Are they stalled until the interrupt handler is executed? How are they scheduled after the interrupt is handled?

References on the subject would also be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually nothing happens, because the int 3 is used only by debuggers to set breakpoints. In case you run your code with a debugger, then it also depends on the debugger what happens. As I used int 3 a couple of years ago, I missed support for lwp. I think if it is now supported, then it should only interrupt the affected thread.